# Exclude an item inside the navbar from collapsing

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So I have a Bootstrap 4 navbar with items from both left and right. This is how looks like.

[image]

And this is how it looks like when collapsed.

[image]

So what I want is for the Sign Up button to be on the right side aligned with the collapse toggle button. How do I do this and is it possible?

Here's my code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <button class="navbar-toggler ml-lg-5 ml-md-5 ml-sm-5" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo03">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-lg-5 ml-md-5 ml-sm-5">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-custom mr-lg-5 mr-md-5 mr-sm-5" type="submit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signupModal">SIGN UP</button>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give `float-right` class explicitly to the button. you can also set floats according to breakpoints check the [Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/float/#responsive)

Another way is `Hide` and `Show` on breakpoints. then you need to have two buttons like this

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-custom mr-lg-5 mr-md-5 mr-sm-5 d-none d-lg-block d-xl-none" type="submit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signupModal">SIGN UP</button>
<button class="btn btn-outline-custom mr-lg-5 mr-md-5 mr-sm-5 float-right d-lg-none d-xl-block" type="submit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signupModal">SIGN UP</button>
```

First button will show when you have large screen only `lg` with this calss `d-none d-lg-block d-xl-none`

Second button will only show on small screen which is less than `lg` with this class `d-lg-none d-xl-block` i have also given a `float-right` class to move it right.

you can see more options [here](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/#hiding-elements)